# Write a table to a file

Tags: output-formatting, output

I want to compute a multidimensional table in Mathematica and write it to an external file. Here is a simple example. I have three lists `x`, `y`, `z` and the output include all possible combinations of sums.

In the output file, I want 27 = 3x3x3 rows. Each row should have four values: `x`, `y`, `z` and `x+y+z`. Here is my code.

```
x = {1, 2, 3};
y = {4, 5, 6};
z = {7, 8, 9};
output = Table[x[[i]] + y[[j]] + z[[k]], {i, 1, 3}, {j, 1, 3}, {k, 1, 3}]
sfile = OpenWrite["C:\\Temp\\test.txt"]
For[i = 1, i <= 3, i++,
 {For[j = 1, j <= 3, j++,
   {For[k = 1, k <= 3, k++,
     Write[sfile, x[[i]], y[[j]], z[[k]], output[[i, j, k]]]]}]}]
Close[sfile]
```

The problem is there is no space in the output file. So I get something like

```
14712
14813
14914
15713
15814
```

but I actually want

```
1 4 7 12
1 4 8 13
1 4 9 14
1 5 7 13
1 5 8 14
```

I need help to get the format above. I am quite new to Mathematica and don't know much about other functions. I am OK with any functions as long as they can generate the output I want. Thank you.

Comment: Any reason for not using `Export`? Do you *need* sequential file operations?

Comment: @YvesKlett I am new to Mathematica and this Write function is the one I found on google. I am ok with any functions. I don't have sequential operations.

Comment: This seems like a strange behavior of `Write`. *Mathematica* does not put a space between expressions.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As suggested by many (@YvesKlett, @acl) you can use `Export` :

```
output2 =  Flatten[Table[{x[[i]], y[[ j]], z[[k]], x[[i]] + y[[j]] + z[[k]]}, 
  {i, 1, 3}, {j, 1, 3}, {k, 1, 3}], 2] ;

Export["test.tsv", output2]
```

Comment: that's the way to do it

Comment: I feel picky: Patrick wanted spaces and you flooded him with tabs! :D

Comment: I was just joking. Of course you can do the tab->space conversion in a thousand ways. Maybe in 2013 even Microsoft Notepad can do that!

Comment: As a curiosity, `Export["test.dat", output2, "FieldSeparators" -> " "]` fulfills all the requirements.

Comment: @b.gatessucks -- Done. Given your name, I think you appreciated the pun about Notepad...

Comment: @Federico Indeed, thanks !

Answer (score 4):

```
sfile = OpenWrite["~/Desktop/test.txt", FormatType -> StandardForm]
For[i = 1, i <= 3, i++, 
 For[j = 1, j <= 3, j++, 
  For[k = 1, k <= 3, k++, 
   Write[sfile, x[[i]], " ", y[[j]], " ", z[[k]], " ", 
    output[[i, j, k]]]]]]
Close[sfile]
```

seems to work. I used `FormatType -> StandardForm` and added the spaces by hand. I'm sure there are better ways (eg with `Export`).

Comment: I think (if I understood the question right) is that he wants a specific output format, likely for use in some other program.

Comment: that is possible, looks like I misunderstood the question

Comment: @s0rce fixed. not elegant though

Comment: You could use `Write[sfile, Sequence @@ Riffle[{x[[i]], y[[j]], z[[k]], output[[i, j, k]]}, " "]]` to automatically intersperse whitespaces.

Comment: @Federico thanks; not sure it's worth the effort here though.

Answer (score 4):

Why not this?

```
x = {1, 2, 3};
y = {4, 5, 6};
z = {7, 8, 9};
output = Table[x[[i]] + y[[j]] + z[[k]], {i, 1, 3}, {j, 1, 3}, {k, 1, 3}]
sfile = OpenWrite["test.txt"]
For[i = 1, i <= 3, i++, For[j = 1, j <= 3, j++, For[k = 1, k <= 3, k++,
   str = ToString[{x[[i]], y[[j]], z[[k]], output[[i, j, k]]}];
   WriteString[sfile, StringReplace[str, "{" | "}" | "," -> ""] <> "\n"]
]]]
Close[sfile]
```

Or this?

```
...
sfile = OpenWrite["test.txt", FormatType -> StandardForm]
...
For[..., For[..., For[...,
   Write[sfile, Sequence @@ Riffle[{x[[i]], y[[j]], z[[k]], output[[i, j, k]]}, " "]]
]]]
...
```

After all this fun with streams, here is a one line solution (read comments after @b.gatessucks's solution, you need his `output2`):

```
output2 = Flatten[Table[{x[[i]], y[[j]], z[[k]], x[[i]] + y[[j]] + z[[k]]}, {i, 1, 3}, {j, 1, 3}, {k, 1, 3}], 2];
Export["test.dat", output2, "FieldSeparators" -> " "]
```

If you look at [CSV](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/format/CSV.html), [TSV](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/format/TSV.html) and [Table](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/format/Table.html) you'll find a lot of useful information.

Note that you don't need to put braces inside `For` like you would do i C.